# opengl rotating an object which is already in rotation something like earth moon rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

```
#include <glut.h>

float _angle = 0.0;

void Draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glPointSize(8);
glPushMatrix();


        glTranslatef(0.3,0.3,0.0);
        glRotatef(_angle, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex3f(0.3, 0.0, 0.0);


    glEnd();
glPopMatrix();  


glFlush();


}

void update(int value)
{
_angle += 3;
if (_angle > 360)
{
_angle -= 360;
}

glutPostRedisplay();
glutTimerFunc(5,update,0);
}

void Initialize() {
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(250, 250);
glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
glutCreateWindow("CSE");
Initialize();
glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
glutTimerFunc(25,update,0);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

i am trying to simulate sun earth and moon rotation. Now i have rotated an object about a specific point in the code above and suppose its the moon orbiting the earth now how can i rotate the whole thing around the origin so that it seems to rotate around the sun.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the pair glPushMatrix()/glPopMatrix(). You just remember that a translation followed by a rotation makes the point rotate around its origin. Bellow it is showed how you can achieved this effect. I just modified a bit your program.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

float _angleMoon = 0.0;
float angleEarth = 0.0;

void Draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPointSize(8);
    glPushMatrix();

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glEnd();

    glRotatef(angleEarth, 0.f, 0.f, 1.0);
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.3,0.3,0.0);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex3f(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glEnd();

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(_angleMoon, 0., 0., 1.);
        glTranslatef(0.3, 0.f, 0.f);
            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();  

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}

void update(int value)
{
    _angleMoon += 3;
    if (_angleMoon > 360)
    {
        _angleMoon -= 360
    }

    angleEarth += 1;
    if (angleEarth > 360)
    {
        angleEarth -= 360;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(5,update,0);
}

void Initialize() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
    glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250, 250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("CSE");
    Initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutTimerFunc(25,update,0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your drawing Order Should be like this, the one you posted in above seems Not correct**

//Correct Drawing Order Should be

```
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //Rotate y axis

glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0); //Move to new position

gluSphere("required arguments");
```

**Lets Say for example in your scene you want to rotate planets around the sun
you need to do something like this...**

**//You need to put every global transformation here..**

```
**//Then Draw the sun**

glPushMatrix();

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glRotatef(360.0 * DayOfYear / 365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //This will self-rotate the sun

gluSphere(quad[0], 1.f, 64, 64);

glPopMatrix();

**//Drawing the Planet X**

glPushMatrix();

glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste parameter afstand tot zon

gluSphere(quad[1], 0.2f, 64, 64);

glPopMatrix();


**//Drawing the Earth**

glPushMatrix();

glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);

glRotatef(360.0*3*DayOfYear/365.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glTranslatef(3.0, 0.0, 0.0); //eerste paramater afstand tot zon

gluSphere(quad[2], 0.6f, 64, 64);

glPopMatrix();
```

**Also you might want to use glutSwapBuffers() in your main rendering function as I dont see that..**